# Concatenate string MAKO

Tags: python, cherrypy, mako

This is my code of Mako but I have the error when i use this code with my server Cherrypy.
The error is

```
SyntaxException: (SyntaxError) invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 1) (u"c=inputp${k}_id\nsomeval= ${urld['kwargs']['${c}']}") in file '/home/user/Scaricati/prototypefin/template/web_editor_parameter_settings.html' at line: 164 char: 1
```

When i wrong with this code? I have to try, if there is a relevant value and print its contents

```
    <div id="sortparam" >

<%
    k = 1
    a=99
%>
<ul  class="ui-sortable" id="sorpara">
    % for k in a:
        <% 
        c=inputp${k}_id
        someval= ${urld['kwargs']['${someval}']} 
        %>
        % if someval is UNDEFINED:
                    <% break %> 
        %     else:
<li id="inputp${id}_id" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>${someval}</li>

        %     endif
        % endfor
  </ul>
</div>
```

Ah I miss what is the variable kwargs??
Kwargs is the content the my file

```
{'demo_title': 'Demo title', 'demo_input_description': 'hola mundo ', 'demo_params_description': '  ', 'demo_wait_description': ' ', 'demo_result_description': '  ', 'images_config_file': 'cfgmydemo.cfg', 'demo_data_filename': 'data_saved.cfg', 'tag': '', 'inputdata1_id': 'id_lsd', 'inputdata1_max_pixels': '1024000' }
```

Where i wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
<div id="sortparam" >

<%
    k = 1
    a=99
%>
<ul  class="ui-sortable" id="sorpara">
    % for k in a:
        <% 
        c='inputp'+k+'_id' 
        %>
        % if c in urld['kwargs'] :

<li id="inputp${k}_id" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>${urld['kwargs']['${c}']}</li>

        %     endif
        % endfor
  </ul>
</div>
```